# USB condensor Mic schizophrenia

Tags: microphone, usb

I have a Audio Technica Atr and I've been using it for about a week now with Garageband/Mac. Today, after creating a new track (compressed) the sound was off. We've built a very professional soundproof booth, and its been working well, the sound has been crisp. But today, the vocal recording has been all over the place. The levels are crazy. This warning keeps showing up saying to monitor feedback, to not monitor, or to ignore monitor protection. I've selected all 3 to fix the problem and it continues to give this static or 'extra' sound making the once crisp vocals messy. How can this 'just happen'? Nothin was wrong yesterday, now today...shrugs What should we do?

Comment: Does the problem persist after unplugging then replugging the mic and/or rebooting the Mac?